# Strange issue with UITableViewCell: UILabel turns into something else?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I got this strange issue while working with iPhone SDK 3.1.2.

My UITableViewCell contains 3 UILabel, each of which is assigned a numeric tag from 1 to 3.

http://img.skitch.com/20100109-gdg9f57999gne3psqmmb3y4nb1.png

The problem is with the first UILabel (highlighted in the above screenshot): I am unable to set its text to anything. Even NSLog its content gives me a `(null)`.

What's interesting is that when I tried to print the UILabel's class name, I got UITableViewCell instead.

http://img.skitch.com/20100110-7jfgipbiskbc9xm68pt3mqfqi.png

Changing this particular UILabel's tag to other number (e.g. 4) makes it work properly. How strange.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Have you clicked on the `UITableViewCell` element in Interface Builder to check what `tag` value it is using?

Comment: Oh, it is set to 1. Changing it to 0 doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Since UITableViewCell automatically has some subviews for accessory views and stuff then maybe one of those is already using the same tag or something?

Comment: @Nimrod: exactly. Use `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating the cell in Interface Builder, I wouldn't use the tag thing anyway. I'd just subclass UITableViewCell as MyCell or something, change your table cell's class to MyCell, then declare some IBOutlets in MyCell that you can connect the subviews to. That also allows you to define some convenience methods/properties for the cell as well.

Then you can forget the tags and just do myCellInstance.nameLabel.text = @"Joebob Briggs" or whatever.

Comment: No need to subclass. @gcamp is correct, you can find the labels in `cell.contentView`.

Comment: Well, it may not be needed but to me the tag thing is more like a last resort because you now have to manually keep some constants in sync. If you use the tag number thing, at least add some stuff like "#define kNameLabelTag 1" somewhere to help keep things in sync. Unfortunately IB won't let you type that define in for the tag, but will keep IBOutlets in sync automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You must be checking into the `cell.contentView` not the view itself. :)